# Pandas - groupby all columns and mark in original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` with columns `'Id'` which is unique, and `'A', 'B', 'C'`, etc...

There are different rows where all values `'A', 'B', 'C'` are the same. I'd like to give them a group name (a running index from 1).

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 1, 1, 2], "B": [3, 4, 4, 4], "C": [5, 5, 5, 5]})
df
Out[127]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  3  5
1  1  4  5
2  1  4  5
3  2  4  5
```

Will become

```
   A  B  C  grp
0  1  3  5    1
1  1  4  5    2
2  1  4  5    2
3  2  4  5    3
```

I know I can groupby `['A', 'B', 'C']` and get the keys, but than, I have to iterate over the keys and Dataframe in an un-optimized matter. I'm failing to do it in an optimized way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.ngroup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html):

```
df['grp'] = df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C']).ngroup() + 1
print (df)

   A  B  C  grp
0  1  3  5    1
1  1  4  5    2
2  1  4  5    2
3  2  4  5    3
```

If columns are sorted:

```
df['grp'] = pd.factorize([tuple(x) for x in df.values])[0] + 1
```

Comment: ngroup() ... damnit I used ngroup without brackets and got stuck on that. Thanks jezrael!

Comment: Can you please be more careful before answering duplicates? This is the second time I've caught you tonight.